# add an extra style to this script

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script language="JavaScript">
<!-- Activate cloaking device
document.write('<body background="' + image + '" >')
// Deactivate cloaking device -->
</script>
```

I need to add this extra style on background.

> no-repeat center center fixed

I tried and it doesn't work:

```
document.write('<body background="' + image + '" no-repeat center center fixed>')
```

How do I add this style to background?

Comment: `document.write` is a bad idea though, and using it for a required starting tag is just asking for trouble.  You might want to read this to help avoid bad code samples in the future: http://www.mopedepot.com/jjs/HowToRecognizeBadJavascriptCode.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wow, that is some old piece of script. Comments around script hasn't been needed for very long, and the `language` attribute is replaced by the `type` attribute.

You have to use a CSS style instead of the `background` attribute to add those CSS settings to the style:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write('<body style="background: url("' + image + '") no-repeat center center fixed">');
</script>
```

Writing out the body tag using script may have bad effects on how your page is viewed by search engines. It would be better to create the body element as usual and set the style on it afterwards:

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.body.style.background = 'url("' + image + '") no-repeat center center fixed';
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you don't use the good syntax :

```
document.write('<body style="background:url("' + image + '") no-repeat center center fixed;">');
```

Comment: It's `background: ' + ... ` not equals :)

Comment: `"' + image + '"` should be just `' + image + '`

Answer (score 0):

```
  document.getElementsByTagName('body').style.background = 'url("' + image + '") no-repeat center center fixed';
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use jquery for this - take the latest minimied version and you should be fine

Just define the class with the background

```
.MyClass
{
    background: url("myPNG.png") no-repeat scroll 8px 37px transparent;
 //some more
}
```

then in the javascript part

```
$("#idMyDiv").addClass('MyClass');
```

or remove:

```
$("#idMyDiv").addClass('MyClass');
```

If you do not want to use jquery, just try something like:

```
document.getElementById(id).style.background = "...";
```